# Example for html to pdf converter getting unexpected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

This example is running replica of the attached fiddle (where example is running properly). I am amazed replicating the same is throwing error. Why?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    'body': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('button').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Click</button>
    <div class="container"> 
        Hello! 
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

**jSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/5ud8jkvf/

**ERROR:**

[image]

> **Notes:**
>
> 1. As fiddle is running properly, this example must also run without any error.
> 2. There is no attachment of jQuery file in fiddle, so I dont think jQuery is required or missing in this example.
> 3. Even on adding jQuery files - **Error is gone - but pdf is not getting downloaded.**

Comment: apart from the jQuery being added - and I agree with all posts re that - It requires the container with the text to be saved to have the id of "content" since that is what is called in the function. I used @ankit 's solution below and found that if yIf you add an id to that .container then it saves the document as a pdf with the text in it. If the .container does not have the id - then the pdf document will save, but will have not text in it

Comment: @peterson are you getting any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    'body': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Click</button>
    <div class="container"> 
        Hello! 
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: thanks - i like this and have copied it to use for future use. Only thing - It requires the container with the text to be saved to have the id of "content" since that is what is called in the function. If you add an id to that .container then it saves the document as a pdf with the text in it. If the .container does not have the id - then the pdf document will save, but will have not text in it.

Comment: "Try this: *code*" does not answer OP's question **why?**

Comment: Which question about you tell me?

Answer (score 4):

The console doesn't lies. The fiddle has dependency to jQuery.

[image: jQuery require]

Your markup requires jQuery. Add jQuery to your code ...

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The cause is that you have to add jQuery, like that:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```